# gnuplot fitting with f(x)= x/(x+k)

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to fit a function in gnuplot. My data is:

```
1.0  0.000
2.0  0.00
7.0  15.3
10.0  34.6
20.0  49.3
70.0  82.6
200.0  96.0
1000.0  100.0
```

I wrote a code:

```
set mxtics 2
set mytics 2
set key left top
set ylabel "F'/F"
set xlabel "c [l/{/Symbol m}g]"
f(x)= x/(x+k)

fit f(x) 'adrenalin.txt' using 1:2 via k
plot 'adrenalin.txt' using 1:2 t"" , f(x) t""
```

And the fit is totally of. I have no idea what is wrong. And I have to use `f(x)= x/(x+k)` for fitting.
can anyone helps? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from you data, you need `k > 0`. In that case, your function `x/(x+k)` will always be far off your data which goes up to `100`. So you must either use a function `f(x) = 100*x/(x+k)` or scale your data by a factor of `100`:

```
set mxtics 2
set mytics 2
set key left top
set ylabel "F'/F"
set xlabel "c (in l/{/Symbol m}g)"
f(x)= 100*x/(x+k)

fit f(x) 'adrenalin.txt' using 1:2 via k
plot 'adrenalin.txt' using 1:2 t "" , f(x) t sprintf("x/(x+%.2f)", k)
```

[image]